# Two-pane file manager for Windows with symlink and large file support

Tags: windows, file-management

What [orthodox file managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_manager#Orthodox_file_managers) for Windows support copying symlinks?

Total Commander doesn't, if you copy via F5:

[image: Total commander symlink recursion]

There are no [official plugins for symlink support](http://www.ghisler.com/plugins.htm). I found a plugin called [NTLinks](http://www.totalcmd.net/plugring/ntlinks.html), but it didn't help. Copying via Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V invoked Windows Explorer and created an empty directory named as the symlink.

Others I've tried without luck:

- [(Necromancer's) Dos Navigator](http://ndn.muxe.com/)
- muCommander kept creating a deeper and deeper directory structure as well, instead of copying the symlink

Comment: TC help, section 4.b says "CopyLinks=0 Copy file system links (junctions) as links and not as directories:
0: Copy links as dirs or ignore them (if IgnoreLinks has been set)
1: Copy links without changing the target path of the links
2: Copy links and change the target path to the target drive if the link points to the same drive on which the link itself is located.

c:\path1\link, pointing to c:\path1\path2\linktarget
Copied to d:\trgpath1\trgpath2\link
-> Link now points to d:\trgpath1\trgpath2\path2\linktarget
Note: The function does NOT check whether the target of the link exists or not. "

Comment: Btw, that above is new since v8.50

Comment: TC Plugin DiskInternals Reader: "This plugin offers access to harddisk partitions and disk images.
Native reader for:
Ext2/3/4, ReiserFS, HFS/HFS+, NTFS, Fat/exFAT
Native support for:
- Windows and Linux software raid arrays
- Adaptec, nVidia, Intel, Via, Silicon raid arrays
- MBR, GPT, BSD and Apple partitions
- VMWare, VirtualPC, VirtualBox and Parallels disk images
**100% symbolic links support** for Linux, Mac and Ntfs. First ever Linux and Mac Reader that can display correct size for link that point to file."

Answer (score 1):

I regularly use [MultiCommander](http://multicommander.com/features/features-overview) for my file management needs.  It can be configured with multi-windows, has a command line bar, and supports extensions and plugins.  It does support moving/copying symlinks, as well as, large files.  You can [configure](http://multicommander.com/docs/copymove_operation) how symlinks are handled.  I've replaced my usage of Windows Explorer because MultiCommander can be easily configure for my needs.